# Apply multilingual php with custom javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, html, include, multilingual

I applied the multilingual and i also need to apply in javascript code which part of alerting message.

This is the common.php code.

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX
$CUR_LANG = 'en';

if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])){
    $CUR_LANG = $_COOKIE['lang'];
    setcookie('lang', $CUR_LANG, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}

switch ($CUR_LANG) {
    case 'ko':
            $lang_file = 'ko.php';
            break;
    default:
            $lang_file = 'en.php';
            break;
}
include_once("multilingual/".$lang_file);
?>
```

and this is the signin.html page

```
<?php include_once('top.php'); ?>
<div class="" style="background:#F7F7F7;">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="login" class="animate form">
        <section class="login_content">
            <form id="signin" name="signin" class="signinForm" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" action="signin.html";>
                <input type="hidden" name="act" value="signin">
                <h1>Login Form</h1>
                <div>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" placeholder="<?= $lang['SIGNIN_ENTER_EMAIL'] ?>" required="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userPassword" name="userPassword" placeholder="<?= $lang['SIGNIN_ENTER_PASSWD'] ?>" required="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" id="signin_btn" href="signin.html"><?= $lang['SIGNIN'] ?></a>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="separator">
                    <a class="reset_pass" href="user-password-reset.html"><?= $lang['SIGNIN_RESET_PASSWD'] ?></a>
                    <p class="change_link"><?= $lang['SIGNIN_CREATE'] ?>
                        <a href="signup.html" class="to_register"><?= $lang['SIGNIN_ACCOUNT'] ?></a>
                    </p>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <br />
                    <!--<div>
                        <h1><i class="fa fa-gamepad" style="font-size: 26px;"></i> GAMEPARTY </h1>
                    </div>-->
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- form -->
        </section>
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div><!-- #wrapper -->
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkFormValid() {
        var isFormValid = true;

        $(".signinForm input").each(function(){
            if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
                console.log("(no value)input id : " + this.id);
                isFormValid = false;
            }
        });

        if(isFormValid) {
            checkEmail();
        }else {
            alert("<?= $lang['SIGNUP_ALERT_0'] ?>"); //here is the msg!
        }
}
```

This page includes the top.php and top.php also includes the common.php.

The attached bottom of javascript code is needed to validate and alert the message.
The message show well depends on applied multilingual. However, the custom js files also have these kind of multilingual messages to alert but they just shows php code.

```
function email_form_validation(element) {
var email = element.val();
console.log("email_from_validation : " + email);
var regex = /[0-9a-zA-Z][_0-9a-zA-Z-]*@[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(\.[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+){1,2}$/;

if(regex.test(email)){
    return true;
}else {
    alert("<?= $lang['E_FROM_VAL'] ?>");//This msg isn't applied the mulitilingual.
    element.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

The above is the sample of common.js file and this common.js file is included in top.php file because this is the group of validation that must be needed from all files. How can i figure out this? The msg in common.js appears just like this -> "`<?= $lang['E_FROM_VAL'] ?>`"

How can i bring the php file and show it? Please let me know.

Comment: Try assigning php value to JQuery variable ans then use that variable in alert. `var msg = <?php echo $lang['E_FROM_VAL']; ?>;` an then `alert(msg);`

Comment: @Suyog It had a same result :(

Comment: is `echo $lang['E_FROM_VAL']` giving anything if used in PHP instead of js?

Comment: @Suyog It gives sentences depends on selected language but the custom js file gives nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do. I simply renamed the common.js to val.php and also modified the top.php like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../val.php"></script>
```

I also added the  `<?php include_once('./common/common.php'); ?>` to the val.php

That's all. It works great.